# Vim: Black text on black background

Tags: vim

I have a problem running Vim. I am editing files with recognisable file extensions - .xml, .php - however the text is black. This would not be a problem except I run terminal windows with a black background.

I can get to see my files by setting the terminal session to have a white background, but I would like a fix rather than a workaround.

I have renamed/moved the .vim and .viminfo files in my home directory but that has not magically restored my vim settings (that were fine yesterday morning).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try informing vim that your terminal has a black background with `:set bg=dark`. If your text is still black, try setting an environment variable that says your terminal is capable of color before you start vim by running `export TERM=xterm-color`.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a speedy reply! That worked a treat.

Comment: Add whichever one of those fixed your issue to either `~/.vimrc` or  `~/.bashrc` to make it a permanent preference.

Comment: ...I won't yet! I will reboot and see what happens. If there is no need then I will get a more definitive answer to post here. Obviously, running Ubuntu I only hibernate rather than reboot...

Answer (score 4):

I'm new to this site.

You can definitively set your background color in `$HOME/(.)vimrc` by writing the line

```
set bg=dark
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I cleared out my .vim* files and the colour scheme still persisted, even in new terminal windows. :set bg=dark worked for me, still not sure why!

Comment: And welcome to SE - you will enjoy it...!